# how can i get/set in word Default personal templates location"

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-template

In Word under Options and Save there is the location 
"Default personal templates location".

Word automatically creates it when you save a template for the first time. 
The default is c: \ Users \ [user name] \ Documents \ Custom Office Templates.

Under Word you can use Options.DefaultFilePath (wd ...) 
to access all possible storage locations, but not "Default personal templates location", at least I have not found a way.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I see no 'Default personal templates location' there, only an 'Auto-Recover file location', a 'Default file location' and a 'Server drafts location' (Office 2010).

Comment: The Default personal templates location was introduced with Office 2013 and doesn't exist in 2010. AFAIK, there is no VBA parameter to find it. You may have to check the documents folder for a subfolder called "Custom Office Templates". Here's the most recent list I could find: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wddefaultfilepath